# How to disable 'Proceed to Checkout' button on the cart page?

Tags: checkout, cart

I am trying to make it so PayPal is the only option the purchase products, how do I remove the 'Proceed to Checkout' button so this is the only option?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your magento version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know in which file you need to hide the text "**Proceed to checkout**" , you can use **Magento template path hints** here :  **system> configuration > Advanced > Developer** ....

than switch to **current store under Current configuration scope**

than **enable template path hints** under **Debug** ,  than you can see from which file the text "**Proceed to checkout**" is coming from....

you can see below links for more information  :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature to disable 'Proceed to Checkout' button from admin so here are few ways you can disable it

Comment/Remove this code from
`/public_html/app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage/link.phtml`:

```
<button type="button"
        data-role="proceed-to-checkout"
        title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Proceed to Checkout') ?>"
        data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout":{"checkoutUrl":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCheckoutUrl(); ?>"}}'
        class="action primary checkout<?php echo($block->isDisabled()) ? ' disabled' : ''; ?>"
        <?php if ($block->isDisabled()):?>disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?>>
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span>
```

Another way to remove from layout. Try above if it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check checkout.xml file intoyour theme

```
 <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>
```

comment this code and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `local.xml` file in `your theme` and put this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
  <checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">            
        <remove name="checkout.cart.top_methods"/>
        <remove name="checkout.cart.methods"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.top" as="top_methods_only_paypal" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
            <action method="setIsQuoteAllowed"><value>1</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

</checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

and then add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top_methods_only_paypal");?>` to your `your_theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml`.

Clear chache and refresh.